# XPath function that returns whole subtree under a node

Tags: xpath

Suppose part of my document is

```
<div>
  <b>Hello,</b> world!
</div>
<div>
  <span>
    <b>This</b> is a <b>wonderful</b> day!
  </span>
</div>
```

I want to select the first div, i.e. a div whose children equals `<b>Hello,</b> world!`, how do I write the expression.  Also How about the second one?

Of course I can have a complicated expression like `//div[text()[1] = ' world' and child::b[position()=1 and text='Hello,']]`, but the complexity grows very fast if subtree becomes a little more complicated.

Ideally if would be good to have a function `subtree` and `equals` which returns the subtree and compares two trees, respectively, so I can simply write `equals(subtree(), '<span><b>This</b> is a <b>wonderful</b> day!</span>')`.

Any thoughts?  Is there any function that fits my need?  Thanks.

Comment: Which language / environment are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the first div in your document, use `/descendant::div[1]` -- or -- `(//div)[1]` -- note the parens, they're required to get the right behavior here.

Comparing two elements is a more complicated question.  There isn't anything built into XPath 1 for that. Some environments will support XPath 2, which defines `deep-equal()` -- see http://www.w3.org/TR/2005/CR-xpath-functions-20051103/#func-deep-equal.